# SwiftUI ステッパーでGoogle mapsのズームレベルを変更する

Tags: swift, google-maps, swiftui

いつもお世話になっております。

SwiftUIでGoogle Mapを表示させることが出来たのですが、ステッパーで　＋ーを押した際に、マップのズームレベルを変更するようにしたいですが、うまくいきません。
アドバイスを頂けますでしょうか。

呼び出しもと(一部)
name,latitude,longitudeはJSONファイルから呼び出すようにしております。変数zoomは状態変数@Stateです。

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
                    GoogleMapView(name:self.shop.name,latitude: self.shop.latitude, longitude: self.shop.longitude,zoom: self.$zoom)
            .frame(width:geometry.size.width,height: 300)
                    Stepper(onIncrement: {self.zoom += 5.0}, onDecrement:{self.zoom -= 5.0}){
                        Text("")
                    }
                }
```

呼び出し先 GoogleMapView

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

struct GoogleMapView: UIViewRepresentable {

 let marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
    var name:String
    var latitude:Double
    var longitude:Double
    @Binding var zoom:Float



 /// Creates a `UIView` instance to be presented.
 func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
     // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
     // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: 20)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    //ここでズームレベルが変わる予定だった
    if self.zoom != 20{
    mapView.animate(toZoom: self.zoom)
    }

     return mapView
 }

 /// Updates the presented `UIView` (and coordinator) to the latest
 /// configuration.
 func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Self.Context) {
     // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
    marker.title = self.name
     marker.map = mapView
 }
}
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `mapView.animate(toZoom: self.zoom)`の行を`updateUIView(_:context:)`側に入れると言うのはやってみましたか?

Comment: コメント有難う御座います。試してみましたが、変わりませんでした。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。では、私が思っていたのとは異なる事象のようですね。早く解決できるようお祈りしております。